# Why my C program is not converting decimal numbers which are bigger than 1000 to binary?

Tags: c, function, binary, decimal

This is the function I wrote:

```
int desdvejet(int sk_b)
{
    int b = 0;
    int nr;
    int x = 1;

    while(sk_b != 0)
    {
        nr = sk_b % 2;
        sk_b = sk_b / 2;
        b = b + nr * x;
        x = x * 10;
    }

    return b;
}
```

(sk_b is decimal number)
If I try testing it with number 2487, this is the output I get - 1325862303
Numbers under 1000 work ok.

Comment: Always put each variable declaration on its own line.

Comment: Because your "pretend" binary numbers run out of headroom? The "8-bit" decimal representation `11111111` already needs 24 bits to store it. Suggest using a string. Even a 64-bit integer can only store 19 of your "bits".

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @WeatherVane.  You're trying to create a *display representation;* I suggest you treat it as such.  Create a string as your output, or simply use the `%b` format specifier in a `printf`.

Comment: MSVC also has the (non-standard?) `char * _ui64toa(unsigned long long value, char *buffer, int radix);` which is useful because MS does not support `%b` (non-standard?) format in `printf()` and `sprintf()`.